# PHP - Loop over form fields and display blank ones as well

Tags: php, forms

I've noticed that this code in PHP 5.5 only displays the fields that have a value. It entirely skips the blank ones and won't display their name or value:

```
$msg = '';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $msg .= $key . ': '; 
  if (is_array($value)) {
    foreach($value as $arr_value){
        $msg .= $arr_value . "; ";
    }
  } else {
    $msg .= $value;
  }
  $msg .= "\n";
}
echo $msg;
```

Is there a way to loop and also see the names of the fields that had no values entered when the form was submitted? Thanks.

**Update:** The form has this `enctype`. Could this make a difference? `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

Comment: you must be doing something to the data as by default  empty input names are still submitted.

Comment: (A value is submitted for every *enabled* field.)

Comment: post update: it would take less time to check than to ask us !

Comment: Can you post a sample form with fields where this happens? If `enctype` is `multipart/form-data` could it be that you are looking for values in `$_FILES` and not `$_POST`?

Comment: I wasn't sure if all the fields are sent to `$_POST` automatically. Then it must be some code in a dozen or more JavaScript files written by someone else. One of those is probably removing the blank fields. Thanks for your help.